# extern access modifiers don't work

Tags: f#, pinvoke, access-modifiers

I'm trying to hide my P/Invoke functions, like this one:

```
[<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)>]
extern bool private CreateTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr& phNewTimer, nativeint TimerQueue, WaitOrTimerDelegate Callback, nativeint Parameter, uint32 DueTime, uint32 Period, ExecuteFlags Flags)
```

Strangely, though, the `private` gets ignored -- which is really annoying, because I want to hide all the unwieldy structs and enums associated with these functions.

I guess I could put everything in a private module, so it's not too big of a deal, but am I missing something?

Comment: Smells like a bug; putting these in a private module indeed sounds like the best workaround.

Comment: For what it's worth, this sounds like an excellent use case for an interface file (in other words, using a *.fsi file to hide certain elements).

Comment: In what context is your `extern` function right now? Within a class, or?

Comment: @pblasucci Please, this isn't a "use case". They didn't break access modifier keywords for certain scenarios just to give purpose to another feature. Forgive my tone, but I can't help but be exasperated when people refuse to accept when there's a problem with their favorite languages. It isn't good for the future of the language.

Comment: @Brian Do you guys have a public bug tracker, or is fsbugs@microsoft.com good?

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka: Whoa! take it easy. I didn't say it was or wasn't a bug. I'm not in a position to make that call. I simply suggested a way to solve your problem. Isn't that the point of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
module a =
    [<AbstractClass>]
    type private NativeMethods() =
        [<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="CreateTimerQueueTimer",
                    SetLastError=true)>]
        static extern bool sCreateTimerQueueTimer( (* whatever *) )
        static member CreateTimerQueueTimer = sCreateTimerQueueTimer

    let usedInside = NativeMethods.CreateTimerQueueTimer

module b =
    open a
    // the next line fails to compile
    let usedOutside = NativeMethods.CreateTimerQueueTimer( (* whatever *) )
```

Notes:

- *private* class can be accessed only from the enclosing module, this is what you need, so just wrap the methods in a `NativeMethods` class;
- You cannot set your *extern* method *private* since it wouldn't be accessible from the rest of module `a`;
- *extern* member of a class is always *private*, so there's another method with same signature;
- Finally, use `EntryPoint` to resolve naming.

Comment: I just put the extern calls in a private nested module, and wrapper functions in the public module holding it.